# PHP/CSS how to keep my checkboxs from going past my border

Tags: php, javascript, css, checkbox

Basically I am createing a unknown size of checkboxs that is dependent on the row that is chosen from a table in my database.  The reason I dont know the size is that the user chooses which row they will use with some rows containing what will become 10 checkboxs adn others containing as many as 75.  So the problem is that if the user selects a row with a large amount of options it goes through the border of my div and then forces me to scroll the page down what I am looking for is a way to say >

if(number of checkboxs is >25 )

create a new column on my page

I dont know whether the right way to go about this is to use php or javascript or possibly do it using css I am new to all of these languages so any help no matter how trivial will greatly appreciated.

```
<div id="major1">
<?php   
        $courses=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM MAJORS_CHECKLIST WHERE MAJOR='$major'");
        $courses_row=mysql_fetch_row($courses);
        $count = 0;
        echo "$courses_row[0] <br/>";
        $checkit = 0;
        $sidebyside = 0;
        foreach($courses_row as $i=>$courses_row){
            if($courses_row['$count'] == NULL)
            {
                break;//if we run out of courses stop printing them

            }
            if($courses_row[$count] == $courses_row[0] && $checkit == 0 )
            {

                $checkit = $checkit + 1;
            }
            else
            {       
                echo "<input type='checkbox' value='$courses_row' name='majorCourses[]' />&nbsp;";//answer-$i
                echo "$courses_row<br /> ";

            }
            $count = $count + 1;
            /*$sidebyside++;
            if($sidebyside == 2)//tried using this to put 2 checkboxes side by side that ened up just messing everything up 
            {
                echo "<br/>";
                $sidebyside = 0;
            }*/ 
        }
```

?>

here is my css:

```
   #major1{
color: white;
/*border: 1px solid black;*/
padding: 5px;
float: left;
height:500px;
width:150px;
}
```

Comment: PHP doesn't know about layout, so JavaScript would be a better fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Producing a bunch of checkboxes in the div can be controlled using CSS. Should set the parent div of the checkboxes to the following rules: width:auto; height:auto; padding:10px 10px; position:relative; This is all assuming that the parent div of the checkboxes is a child of another div to control the preferred dimensions

**edit:** if you do not want to want to use css with the methods above, you can control the "X" amount of checkboxes per row. You can create a counter to count how many are being displayed and do a if($counter % X == 0) echo "`</div><div>`"; This is all assuming you have a starting div at the beginning of your code and an ending div at the end of the code.

Comment: that is what i tried with sidebyside by it still breaks in there somwhere even when I take out the <br /> after $courses_row<br />. also I tried using the css I may be doing it wrong but I have a div named content and inside that is my div named major1 I set the values you said to use in the div named content and it didnt work am I doing that right or no......thanks for the help. I just saw the edit so basically your saying to create a new division when ...say I get 25 checkboxs end my major1 div and create a new one

Comment: I got it working the problem was that when I tried useing the sidebyside variable to check how many boxs had been printed I didnt change the width of my div so it still put them underneath one another. I just changed the width and it works fine thatnks for the help I might still try the div that might be a little better looking thanks